# TableView ScrollToIndex When TextArea Is Focused

Tags: ios, uitableview, titanium

I have a tableview and and one of the rows contains a button. When the user presses the button, I append a row to the table that contains a text area. I want the new row to be at the top of the tableview and the keyboard open. Here is what I have tried:

```
function addNewComment() {
    var newComment = new NewComment(tableView.data[0].rows.length);

    //I add the spacer so that if the added row is the last in the table, it can still be at the top of the view
    var spacer = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        height:250,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    });

    //There are 6 rows of information in the table before the comments start
    tableView.appendRow(spacer, {animated:false});
    tableView.insertRowAfter(5, newComment, {animationStyle:Titanium.UI.iPhone.RowAnimationStyle.DOWN});

    //The listener for this just focuses the text area
    Ti.App.fireEvent('newCommentAddedToView');
    tableView.scrollToIndex(6,{animated:true,position:Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewScrollPosition.TOP});
}
```

When this runs, it is as if the last line of the method isn't called. The new row scrolls into view but not all the way to the top. It only scrolls into view enough to see what you are typing in the text area. You can then manually scroll the row so that it aligns with the top but I'd like to do this automatically. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that index correct?

Answer (score 0):

Setting focus on TextField or TextArea triggers scrolling to place where you are typing. Try calling scrollToIndex after focus is already set in the TextArea.

Comment: That is what the last two lines do. The `newCommentAddedToView` event just calls focus on the text field.

Comment: Yes, but firing event is asynchronous, so probably in your case tableView.scrollToIndex() is executed before eventListener handles newCommentAddedToView. You can put two different console.logs() to make sure in what order code executes.